# Wxpython log message window with button control

Tags: python, logging, wxpython, wxwidgets

I’m trying to design a log message  window, that collects the logs from all modules and displays it. There is a custom handler that redirects logs into wx.textctrl and displays it. Instead I'm looking for a different custom handler which redirects the logs as list and I should be able to select either INFO, ERROR, DEBUG,WARNING or ALL messages based on button click. Any hint will be helpful. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OSwY.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what exactly is this question about, so the answer can only be relatively general, but maybe this could still be useful, so:

In C++ you can do this by defining your own class deriving from `wxLog` and overriding its `DoLogRecord()` method, which allows you to get access to different fields of the log record (e.g. text and time are separate) as well as to the log level.

This class would use either `wxListCtrl` or `wxDataViewCtrl` to show the records, with different fields in the different columns.

Comment: Thanks for the information. To be more precise, I want a log UI which can be able to filter DEBUG, INFO, WARNING or ERROR and also messages are arranged according to timestamp. I want to use only wxpython and not switch to other languagesor packages.

Comment: I have added a sample image for reference purpose.